# Does this solution work for the closest pair problem?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have been looking for the solution for the closest pair problem in Python, but all the solutions were completely different from mine.

Here is the code that finds the closest pair of points on a 2D dimension.

```
def closest_pair_two_axes(xarr, yarr):
    pairs = []
    # doesn't really depend if xarr or yarr because the lengths are the same
    for i in range(len(xarr)):
        pairs.append([xarr[i], yarr[i]])

    # Finds the difference between each point
    dist_arr = []
    for i in range(1, len(pairs)-1):
        for j in range(i, len(pairs)):
            diff_x = pairs[j][0] - pairs[j - i][0]
            diff_y = pairs[j][1] - pairs[j - i][1]

            diff = (diff_x ** 2 + diff_y ** 2) ** 0.5
            dist_arr.append(round(diff, 2))

    index = dist_arr.index(min(dist_arr))
    closest_distance = dist_arr[index]

    return closest_distance
```

`xarr` and `yarr` are just the names of arrays for the x and y coordinates. In the function, I combine both arrays into a dictionary containing sets of coordinates. After that, I iterate through every possible combination of the coordinates and find the distance between each one of them. In the end, I find the minimum distance, trace it back to the pair it belongs to, and then return it to the user.

This code works but I am not sure if it works correctly and if the result really is the closest pair. Is the code correct?

EDIT:
I changed [j-1] to [j-i] so that it will iterate through every pair possible. Also, I solved the problem using another person's algorithm(the right algorithm) and got the same answer as I did with my algorithm. It might not be the fastest and cleanest code, but it works!

Comment: @JohnColeman CR is only for code OP knows to be working to the best of their knowledge. OP needs to test their code before it's on topic anywhere. Guseyn013, What's the closest pair problem exactly? If this is from an algorithm site, does the code pass their tests? If not, have you written your own tests?

Comment: You need to write some unit tests! :-)

Comment: Also, save yourself some compute and don't take the square root.

Comment: The code doesn't work because it only considers points that are adjacent in the list (indexed by `j` and `j-1`). You won't find anything similar on the web because your solution uses `O(n^2)` extra space, and `O(n^2)` time. The problem can be solved with `O(1)` extra space, and `O(n^2)` time, and most solutions on the web will try to do better than `O(n^2)` time.

Comment: There is a reason why all the solutions are different from yours. Yours implements an obvious brute-force algorithm, which is too slow. Try your code on 100,000,000 random points to see what I mean. Existence of a *fast* non-obvious solution is what makes the problem interesting. Why do you think you can find it everywhere?

Comment: @user3386109 In my new edit, I changed `[j-1]` to `[j-i]` and now it works properly!

Comment: Also, should I delete this post since the problem was solved or let it stay here?

Comment: Deleting counts against you, so I'd just let it stay. Congrats on getting it working :)